# Monitoring short lived python Batch Job Processes using Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

How can I monitor my python processes (say some script that gets triggered periodically by Cron daemon) using Prometheus?

Note that this is not a web application but a short-lived process that gets launched periodically by the Cron daemon. This script comes up, does its job, and terminates. The same python script gets launched multiple times a day (approximately 100k times) by cron daemon. I want to capture multiple stats from various runs of this script (for example, the time it takes to run a particular function, how much CPU and memory it consumes, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at [Prometheus' Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/): whenever your script completes, it can push the metrics it collected (e.g. a histogram of how long your function calls took, total CPU utilization, peak memory utilization etc.).

You seem to be saying your script will run approximately once a second. I am hoping that means something along the lines of "once every 5 minutes for each of 300 tenants". In a case like this, you would push your metrics with something like a `tenant_id` label and be able to see either per-tenant or aggregated metrics.

If your script runs once a second with the same parameters/configuration, then you'll probably lose some of the metrics because multiple scripts may terminate within the same second, all push their metrics and only the last one's metrics will get collected by Prometheus (as I believe you can't set a collection interval lower than 1 second in Prometheus).

Comment: Thanks @Alin for the response. Script comes up with a set of parameters each time it runs. One of the parameter is a key which is different for each run, I guess I can use that to distinguish one run from another.

Comment: Also note that each run of a script writes some information in the file system - for example, if it succeeded or failed or running etc. And the path to a file system is something like /script_name/date/key/, since the directory path is dated and it also has a key in the path no two runs will end up writing data in same set of files. Do I still need a pushgateway? Can't script write metrics to the Filesystem in this dated dir and somehow I publish these metrics to prometheous?

Comment: Well, something needs to push metrics (via Pushgateway) to Prometheus. Whether it's your script directly or something reading your script's output. I'd go with the former as it's simpler.

Comment: Regarding the "key which is different for each run", that's not such a great idea. You'll end up with an arbitrarily large number of labels, which is something Prometheus doesn't deal very well with. Either you push the metrics for each run whenever it is done and are OK with losing some of the metrics or go with a separate tool that parses the output files of your script runs and aggregates everything. Then you wouldn't push to Pushgateway, just have that tool export a `/metrics` endpoint with whatever metrics it has aggregated from the files.

Comment: Oh, one more thing that I just remembered: since you say your script runs each produce a log, you may want to look into mtail -- https://github.com/google/mtail -- which is an exporter that tails logs to produce Prometheus metrics. I haven't used it myself but I've seen it used with good results.

Comment: Thanks Alin :), I will check this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pushgateway and `prometheus_client`:

```
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Gauge, push_to_gateway

registry = CollectorRegistry()
g = Gauge('job_last_success_unixtime', 'Last time a job successfully finished', registry=registry)
g.set_to_current_time()
push_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job='job_a', registry=registry)
```