# Monitor backup script with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to monitor my simple bash script for backup cassandra, so here is my script

## !/bin/bash

```
### Check for incomplete backups

if medusa list-backups  | grep Incomplete 
then
echo cassandra_backup_status{status='"success"'} 0  > /var/lib/node_exporter/textfile_collector/cassandra_backup_status.prom
else
echo "all is ok tho"
fi
```

so as you can see here, i use textfile collector, which node_exporter builtin
and then i want to select this using alertmanager like this
cassandra_backup_status =! 0; then alert_to_telegram

is this scenario right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitoring short lived python Batch Job Processes using Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920309/monitoring-short-lived-python-batch-job-processes-using-prometheus)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the means to expose the metric (textfile or push gateway). The approach is not right because:

- the metric will only be present in one state (namely when it fails) which means you won't be able to detect if/when the script run
- in the other case or your `if`, you don't remove the textfile which means that it will always stay (with a failed state)

Finally, the label is not meant to pass a state, but only the value should report that. It will also save you a lot of pain when determining what is the last state; whenever a label change a new metric is created and the old one is still in prometheus until it become stale (5 minutes).

As a conclusion, the script should:

- use a metric with value 0 for failed and 1 for success
- add a metric to indicate the date of the last run of the script (to detect flatlining)

Appart from that, I recommand that you use a temporary file or use [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) to write atomically to the file.